# Asymptotics of the MLE: a different flavor of proof? [Reference request]

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, asymptotics, efficiency

I'm currently trying to understand more about the properties of the maximum likelihood estimator.
It's known that, in the large data-limit, the MLE becomes an unbiased estimator with almost Gaussian distribution with minimum variance (it's efficient). In math, if we note $\theta_0$ the true value generating the data and $\hat \theta$ the MLE (and $I_0$ the Fisher information of the data-generating process):

$$ \sqrt n (\hat \theta - \theta_0) \rightarrow N(0, (n I_0)^{-1} ) $$

The conventional proof relies on computing the distribution of the empirical likelihood function, but are there other possibilities ? In particular, I'm wondering if somebody as come up with an explanation using information theory ideas.

Comment: This could be of interest: http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/lecam/simple.pdf   And for use of information theory, see  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31266/information-theoretic-central-limit-theorem/33264#33264